# What if I void a license for an HTML5 website?

Tags: copyright, template, licenses

We are developing a new website for a group of people initializing their first startup and started looking for good looking  templates and found one interesting from a popular site selling web templates/PSDs.

Fortunately, or unfortunately, we somehow managed to get the complete template of that particular website that we found interesting. Since we are developing a website for a company, can we proceed with the template in our hand / apply for a license from the site selling the template?

Comment: So you are asking if it's ok to steal other people's work?

Comment: We are mainly interested to identify the be the pros and cons of both.Its just a static HTML5 css3 jquery website.

Comment: You should pay for the license as soon as possible - that's a really unprofessional way to develop for a company, and a bad start for them.

Answer (score 1):

Dump it, apply for a license, download their current, up-to-date package, install it and proceed from there. If you liked what you saw, then your purchased install will be legitimate.

Proceeding with the current state of affairs without purchasing the template is theft and often Karmic in that when you run into problems in implementation, you have no product support to fall back on. Also, when the site goes live, you will probably find there were a couple necessary updates for bugs or security patches.

Integrity is maintained, not regained.